# MyGet throwing repository URL is of an invalid format

Tags: azure-devops, myget

I added a new build source on myget.org using VSTS, but MyGet is throwing this error:

[image]

The thing is, the URL shouldn't be incorrect... it was setup by MyGet itself, since I used the wizard.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the authentication information.

1. Log on to your VSTS
2. Click your account > Security

[image]

3. Select Alternate authentication credentials (Personal access token is ok too)
4. Check enable alternate authentication credentials and create an alternate authentication credentials
5. Log on to your MyGet > Select Build Services > Click Edit to edit your build service

[image]

6. Type user name and password (if you are using Personal Access Token, the user name can be any, such as test, user etc…)

[image]

7. Start build

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why that wasn't requested at setup. Thanks anyway.